# jQuery dotdotdot read more

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use the jQuery plugin dotdotdot to add ellipses & a "read more" link to a chunk of text. However, with the suggested way of adding the read more content, the whole chunk of text is appended to the end of the preview before the preview disappears. I feel like this makes the action look kind of clunky, as the text appears, and then shifts to eliminate the duplicate text. Is there any way to fix this?

Eg.

```
This is a long sentence that ... READ MORE

This is a long sentence that ... READ MORE This is a long sentence that gets cut off.
```

Currently my code is as such:

```
    $("a.read-more").click(function() {
      var content = $(".summary").triggerHandler("originalContent");
      $(".summary").append(content);
      $("a.read-less").show();
})
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a link that you could share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try hiding the "Read More" before you append the content.

```
$("a.read-more").click(function() {
      var content = $(".summary").triggerHandler("originalContent");
      $(this).hide();
      $(".summary").append(content);
      $("a.read-less").show();
});
```

Comment: Added a span for the cut off text, and hid the span & the read more link. Works great! Thanks!